# query optimization of a left join

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, mysql-5.6, query-performance

I have the following query written into the slow log (`mysql-slow.log`).

I don't have much idea how to optimize this query. I already have indexes for:

1. `mode`,
2. `f.user_id`... etc

but doesn't seem to be helping me. Mind you, the table Engine is `InnoDb`.

```
# Query_time: 10.830652  
    Lock_time: 0.000058  
    Rows_sent: 1  
    Rows_examined: 18194  
    Rows_affected: 0
# Bytes_sent: 75
SET timestamp=1439531119;
SELECT 
  COUNT(u.user_id) 
FROM (
    users AS u 
    LEFT JOIN photos AS f 
        ON u.user_id=f.user_id 
        AND f.main='Y')  
WHERE  u.mode NOT IN('suspended','deleted','hidden')  
AND u.activated='Y';
```

[image: Explain query output]

Comment: Please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Table_Name\G` for all the tables in the query.

Comment: Please use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) and add the results to the question too. That shows some expected numbers of rows and used indexes.

Comment: Just a note: "left join" is type of "outer join" not "inner".

Comment: It appears to me that this particular query is just an indication of performance bottleneck, not the problem itself. Note : `rows_examined` is less than 20k, such a query by itself can't take 10 seconds. The system seems to struggle for resources (I'd start checking all possible metrics), or there are some serious issues with hard drive.

Comment: A potentially noteworthy red flag is that the query also isn't actually returning anything particularly meaningful.  It's counting the users who are activated and not suspended, deleted or hidden... whether or not they have a photo with main = 'Y'.  If a user has more than one photo with main = 'Y' it will count that user more than once.

Comment: i have added the "Explain Query output" as well to the question

Comment: Also in addition please note cant be a problem with the resources it has 32GB memory and 8 cpu hosted only this website with max only 100 users per time.

Comment: And is it configured to use that memory? (innodb_buffer_pool size and other variables)

Comment: Yeah those are set according to the mysql turner script. . Also please note that all i want to do is count the number of users who has a photo.  May be there is a another way to fo the same

Comment: This counts all users (left join so not having a photo still counts) and if one user can have multiple photos then it could count one user multiple times.

Comment: Please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;` for both tables and the EXPLAIN output in text format, not as an image.

Comment: `f` needs `INDEX(user_id, main)` (in either order).

Comment: Remove `LEFT`; see if you get the same answer.  Then ask yourself which answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Often times slow queries are caused by a lack of index on a column that is being used in a where or join clause.

Try indexing all of the following:

- u.user_id
- f.user_id
- f.main
- u.mode
- u.activated

You could also try moving f.main='Y' to the WHERE condition - I believe it will result in the same outcome.

Comment: Random indexes on everything and anything is often not good either.